# Who called my DBus API in Linux system

Tags: linux, dbus, sender

The scenario is like this:

In a Linux based handheld device I have a C app which has dbus APIs ready to be called by 3rd party apps. The DBus APIs are called during booting time.

Is there any system API I can use to in my functions to print the caller's ID and save it to syslog?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

`/org/freedesktop/DBus` object on the `org.freedesktop.DBus` bus has two methods belonging to the `org.freedesktop.DBus` interface (oh, well): `GetConnectionUnixUser` and `GetConnectionUnixProcessID`. Both accept a string—unique connection name which can be obtained by calling `dbus_message_get_sender` (or whatever method your high-level API wrapper offers).

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that since this answer was written, the `org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionCredentials` method has been added too, which should be used in preference to `GetConnectionUnixUser` and `GetConnectionUnixProcessID`. It means one method call instead of two, eliminates some race conditions, and gives you additional information about security labels. See the specification: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-get-connection-credentials

Comment: Credentials-object won't get peer unix user ID nor process ID in all cases as there are multiple types of authentication available.